# Why is there no 20" HP LCD information in Raring?

Tags: resolution, display

My HP S2031 is limited to 1024x768 max.

I have spent hours tracking this down.
I've installed a new driver and had to remove it because it broke Unity.
I read about the `amdconfig` command, which is not on my system.
I learned about the `xrandr` & `cvt` functions and attempted to use them with no change.
 `xrandr --newmode "1600x900R" 97.50 1600 1648 1680 1760 900 903 908 926 +hsync -vsync`

Using **grep** I found the file /usr/share/hwdata/MonitorsDB, 
and I have determined that my monitor is not on the list.
In fact, there are no 20" 1600x900 native resolution HP brand LCDs in the file!

Within the "Displays" application the monitor is listed as Unknown.
Is this the reason for the lack of proper graphics driver? 
Why my monitor can only be set to display a distorted 1024x768 or 800x600?

**Does anyone know the format of the data to add to this MonitorsDB file, and would it work?**

My system's output from  `cvt -r 1600 900` (what I used) is shown above.
**cvt 1600 900**   yields:
`# 1600x900 59.95 Hz (CVT 1.44M9) hsync: 55.99 kHz; pclk: 118.25 MHz
Modeline "1600x900_60.00"  118.25  1600 1696 1856 2112  900 903 908 934 -hsync +vsync`

**gtf 1600 900 60**  yields:
`# 1600x900 @ 60.00 Hz (GTF) hsync: 55.92 kHz; pclk: 119.00 MHz
Modeline "1600x900_60.00"  119.00  1600 1696 1864 2128  900 901 904 932  -HSync +Vsync`

---

EDIT:

### **Users with less than 10 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. You can answer in 5 hours. Until then please use comments, or edit your question instead.**

To fix no 1600x900 resolution for HP 20" monitor, I created ***/usr/local/bin/fix-resolution.sh*** containing these four lines
  **#!/bin/sh**
  **xrandr --newmode "1600x900R" 97.50 1600 1648 1680 1760 900 903 908 926 +hsync -vsync**
  **xrandr --addmode VGA-0 1600x900R**
  **xrandr --output VGA-0 --mode 1600x900R**
These xrandr changes will disappear on reboot, so I made the script executable and then created the file ***/etc/xdg/autostart/fix-resolution.desktop*** containing these 4 lines
  **[Desktop Entry]**
  **Name=fix resolution**
  **Exec=/usr/local/bin/fix-resolution.sh**
  **NoDisplay=false**
to automatically execute the script on startup.
The *fix-resolution.sh* script works when executed from the terminal after startup, 
but does not automatically run during startup. I assume that this is not the proper place to ask a question about the startup sequence, I'm just letting you know what is needed to fix this problem in case anyone else has it too.

Comment: Your edit should have been an answer, which you can do for your own questions.  I've turned your edit/answer into an actual answer, and marked it so I won't get any rep from it.  You may mark that as your answer in a couple of days.

Comment: I apologize, then, I misread your question in the answer (answer deleted)

Answer (score 1):

For the HP S2031 monitor I created a `~/.xprofile` patch containing these 3 lines.

```
xrandr --newmode "1600x900R" 97.50 1600 1648 1680 1760 900 903 908 926 +hsync -vsync
xrandr --addmode VGA-0 1600x900R
xrandr --output VGA-0 --mode 1600x900R
```

The lines are executed when X starts and causes an ugly display glitch for a few seconds, but the end result is a crystal clear 1600x900 display.  Hopefully this oversight gets rectified in 13.10.